# SQL query too slow in python pandasql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have create a query with pandasql in the following code :

```
csv_path = "C:/..."
data = read_csv(csv_path, sep=';', encoding='utf-8') 

q= """
SELECT Address
FROM data
WHERE Id == 4357;
"""

print pandasql.sqldf(q,locals())
```

So I create a `dataframe` from `.csv` file and then I make this query

My original `.csv` file is 440k + rows long, while coding I am working on a 50 rows long file and even with that file it takes 1  minute for make the query and it use approximately 1.9 Go of the physical memory

So I don't understand why it takes that much time and memory. I looked on some websites but there is not that much infos about pandasql out there

Comment: This API looks weird. The variable that is the table of data is not specified. Instead, it appears that the code here https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/blob/master/pandasql/sqldf.py guesses the source of your data based on the names of your tables in your query. I'd have thought the correct query is "SELECT Address FROM data WHERE Id = 4357;" but you said the query succeeded.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake re-writing the code.